# typings/image.d.ts && cssmodule.d.ts not found in Vite build NX 16.5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, nrwl-nx, nx-monorepo

#### Current Behavior

I have migrated from create-react-app to Vite.
Running the app & build locally works fine but when I try to deploy the changes via bitbucket pipeline I get this error.

Nx version: 16.5.3

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowJs": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "types": ["vite/client", "vitest"]
  },
  "files": [],
  "include": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  ],
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json"
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "types": ["node", "vite/client"]
  },
  "files": ["../../node_modules/@nx/react/typings/cssmodule.d.ts", "../../node_modules/@nx/react/typings/image.d.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "src/**/*.spec.js",
    "src/**/*.test.js",
    "src/**/*.spec.jsx",
    "src/**/*.test.jsx"
  ],
  "include": ["src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.jsx", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

**tsconfig.spec.ts**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "types": ["vitest/globals", "vitest/importMeta", "vite/client", "node"]
  },
  "include": [
    "vite.config.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "src/**/*.spec.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.js",
    "src/**/*.spec.js",
    "src/**/*.test.jsx",
    "src/**/*.spec.jsx",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "files": ["../../node_modules/@nx/react/typings/cssmodule.d.ts", "../../node_modules/@nx/react/typings/image.d.ts"]
}
```

**tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
     "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2017", "DOM", "ES2018.Promise", "ESNext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

#### Expected Behavior

The tsconfig should be able to detect the path for typings on nodemodules

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Create a nx  react with vite bundler application
2. Deploy using bitbucket pipeline

#### Nx Report

```bash
Node   : 20.4.0
   OS     : darwin-arm64
   yarn   : 1.22.19

   nx (global)        : 16.5.3
   nx                 : 16.5.3
   @nx/js             : 16.5.3
   @nx/jest           : 16.5.3
   @nx/linter         : 16.5.3
   @nx/workspace      : 16.5.3
   @nx/cypress        : 16.5.3
   @nx/devkit         : 16.5.3
   @nx/eslint-plugin  : 16.5.3
   @nx/react          : 16.5.3
   @nrwl/tao          : 16.5.3
   @nx/vite           : 16.5.3
   @nx/web            : 16.5.3
   @nx/webpack        : 16.5.3
   nx-cloud           : 16.1.0
   typescript         : 5.1.6
```

#### Failure Logs

```
error TS6053: File '/nx-wspace/node_modules/@nx/react/typings/cssmodule.d.ts' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
error TS6053: File '/nx-wspace/node_modules/@nx/react/typings/image.d.ts' not found.
  The file is in the program because:
    Root file specified for compilation
Found 2 errors.
 >  NX   Found type errors. See above.
Error: Found type errors. See above.
    at validateTypes (/node_modules/@nx/vite/src/utils/executor-utils.js:28:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async viteBuildExecutor (/node_modules/@nx/vite/src/executors/build/build.impl.js:34:9)
```

#### Operating System

- [X] macOS

#### Additional Information

*No response*

Comment: The work around is to move the .dts entries from the files array to the include array in the tsconfig.app.json.
This is required only for my vite app but this config works fine with other CRA apps present in the repo.
Also the react -Vite generators woulld include .dts file inside files